# Why is Eigen Library giving incorrect eigen values when value is expected to be less than 1 for a complex float 24x24 Matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I’m getting mixed results for Eigen Library eigen solver with a complex float on a 24 x 24 array.  Matlab is able to produce eigen values and vectors for the array that are correct.  The Eigen library can only correctly identify the last 8 values and vectors.  The correctness seems to correspond to the expected eigen value.  When the expected eigen value is going to be less than one, then the eigen value returned by eigen library is incorrect.  To verify correctness, I’m using the formula for matrix A where:

```
A*eigen_vector == eigen_value * eigen_vector
```

C++ Code:

```
Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXcf> ces(A);
eigen_vectors = ces.eigenvectors();
eigen_values = ces.eigenvalues().array().abs();
Eigen::ComputationInfo info = ces.info();

auto vals = ces.eigenvalues();
auto left = (A * eigen_vectors.col(i)).eval();
auto right = (eigen_values(i) * eigen_vectors.col(i)).eval();
```

The value of info is success(0).

Below are the results for the 1st, 15th, 16th and 24th columns.  Again columns 1 through 16, where expected eigen value is less than 1) are wrong and columns 17 through 24 (where expected eigen values are greater than 1) are correct.

The eigen value for the first column is 3.18247221e-05 and the remaining results are:

```
Eigen Vector:  0.116856-0.101679i -0.053167-0.045308i 0.189751-0.007320i -0.094731-0.100459i 0.031872+0.036732i -0.077513-0.235932i -0.146664-0.057607i 0.240418-0.386918i -0.242117+0.152045i 0.029276-0.015581i -0.163710-0.010984i 0.034757+0.166928i 0.393912+0.028451i -0.244973-0.073360i -0.037887+0.074877i -0.009600-0.200368i -0.115676-0.144717i 0.058291+0.083560i -0.134150+0.110078i
-0.267531-0.144257i 0.111152-0.071048i -0.016644-0.122138i 0.053874+0.033652i 0.084331-0.034665i
```

Left Result

```
0.000221-0.000029i 0.000160+0.000070i 0.000084+0.000041i -0.000023+0.000058i -0.000231+0.000050i -0.000078-0.000063i -0.000166-0.000147i -0.000146+0.000069i -0.000067+0.000046i -0.000162-0.000103i -0.000244+0.000027i-0.000177+0.000107i -0.000151+0.000122i -0.000169+0.000244i -0.000070+0.000481i 0.000010+0.000243i 0.000128+0.000313i 0.000086+0.000238i 0.000103+0.000207i 0.000283+0.000114i 0.000381-0.000028i 0.000185-0.000044i 0.000198-0.000041i 0.000137+0.000046i
```

Right Result

```
0.000005+0.000001i 0.000000-0.000002i 0.000004+0.000005i 0.000001-0.000004i -0.000000+0.000002i 0.000004-0.000007i -0.000002-0.000005i 0.000014-0.000002i -0.000009-0.000003i 0.000001+0.000000i -0.000003-0.000004i -0.000003+0.000004i 0.000007+0.000010i -0.000003-0.000008i -0.000003+0.000001i 0.000005-0.000004i 0.000001-0.000006i -0.000001+0.000003i -0.000005-0.000001i -0.000002-0.000010i 0.000004+0.000001i 0.000003-0.000003i 0.000000+0.000002i 0.000003+0.000001i
```

The eigen value for the 16th column is 0.000447395432 and the remaining results are:

Eigen Vector

```
-0.129462+0.080319i 0.503447-0.030272i -0.250503+0.133473i 0.078905-0.110744i -0.103717-0.274465i 0.002387-0.044809i 0.179838-0.055467i -0.179086+0.207490i 0.254963-0.022882i -0.002364+0.029277i -0.063116+0.014189i -0.029085-0.161171i 0.019494+0.168846i -0.155084-0.110897i 0.196219-0.127527i -0.067199+0.065707i -0.077747+0.136864i 0.177431+0.031691i 0.191456-0.072533i -0.226178-0.096186i -0.081929-0.098818i 0.029809+0.104811i -0.046287-0.080181i 0.033617-0.028921i
```

Left Result

```
-0.000309+0.000206i -0.000179+0.000137i 0.000086+0.000257i -0.000004+0.000346i 0.000141+0.000296i -0.000031+0.000223i -0.000126+0.000443i -0.000187+0.000181i -0.000325+0.000122i -0.000282+0.000032i -0.000077-0.000134i 0.000222-0.000206i 0.000171-0.000282i 0.000063-0.000368i 0.000782-0.000860i 0.000485-0.000464i 0.000068-0.000452i 0.000080-0.000582i -0.000048-0.000478i -0.000525-0.000506i -0.000761-0.000059i -0.000264+0.000076i -0.000411+0.000162i -0.000092+0.000224i
```

Right Result

```
-0.000062+0.000029i 0.000225+0.000012i -0.000118+0.000047i 0.000041-0.000045i -0.000033-0.000127i 0.000003-0.000020i 0.000083-0.000016i -0.000090+0.000083i 0.000115+0.000002i -0.000003+0.000013i -0.000029+0.000003i -0.000005-0.000073i 0.000000+0.000076i -0.000063-0.000057i 0.000094-0.000047i -0.000033+0.000026i -0.000041+0.000057i 0.000077+0.000023i 0.000089-0.000023i -0.000096-0.000054i -0.000032-0.000048i 0.000008+0.000048i -0.000017-0.000038i 0.000016-0.000011i
```

The eigen value for the 17th column is 0.000447395432 and the remaining results are:

Eigen Vector

```
-0.180662+0.000949i 0.175624-0.044660i -0.175235+0.118171i -0.031841+0.032150i 0.103090+0.197154i -0.012064+0.306235i -0.047170-0.072482i 0.026343-0.333177i 0.199390-0.020131i -0.016225+0.141814i -0.035368-0.182202i -0.311619+0.344249i -0.139175-0.048998i -0.147191-0.106527i 0.081654+0.099897i -0.065063+0.054494i -0.072711-0.007868i -0.202887-0.219343i 0.085549-0.128106i -0.032125-0.061846i 0.096094+0.176484i -0.015189-0.226712i 0.056063+0.011951i -0.102028-0.083975i
```

Left Result

```
-23.387611+0.122978i 22.735226-5.781250i -22.685196+15.297768i -4.122077+4.161827i 13.345421+25.522297i -1.561729+39.643456i -6.106293-9.383188i 3.410229-43.131386i 25.811787-2.606186i -2.100426+18.358337i -4.578606-23.587095i -40.340446+44.564548i -18.016869-6.343142i -19.054581-13.790518i 10.570524+12.932138i -8.422680+7.054350i -9.412903-1.018623i -26.264793-28.395016i 11.074594-16.583862i -4.158801-8.006237i 12.439541+22.846725i -1.966396-29.348801i 7.257420+1.547224i -13.208191-10.870808i
```

Right Result

```
-23.387533+0.122920i 22.735312-5.781419i -22.684887+15.297785i -4.122017+4.161916i 13.345476+25.522495i -1.561712+39.643520i -6.106310-9.383076i 3.410251-43.131256i 25.811895-2.606046i -2.100339+18.358484i -4.578590-23.586895i -40.340446+44.564613i -18.016870-6.343021i -19.054562-13.790393i 10.570497+12.932129i -8.422701+7.054466i -9.412786-1.018598i -26.264687-28.394962i 11.074714-16.583828i -4.158720-8.006290i 12.439752+22.846632i -1.966295-29.348902i 7.257586+1.547073i -13.208040-10.870924i
```

The eigen value for the 24th column is 19668.7812 and the remaining results are:

Eigen Vector

```
0.097742+0.000000i 0.080856+0.054807i -0.037769+0.111747i -0.162293+0.061423i -0.282967+0.048335i -0.146718-0.022603i -0.197100-0.133459i -0.163493-0.018498i -0.145976-0.042051i -0.170700-0.097671i -0.129707-0.021901i -0.075060+0.088880i -0.020776+0.123144i -0.050064+0.159086i 0.101916+0.434050i 0.121622+0.270482i 0.208905+0.199689i 0.180265+0.148550i 0.152823+0.123853i 0.227151-0.035251i 0.219237-0.129511i 0.108033-0.057653i 0.100164-0.061891i 0.041450+0.030553i
```

Left Result

```
1922.458130-0.000084i 1590.333374+1077.984741i -742.875000+2197.920166i -3192.101807+1208.124023i -5565.626465+950.697693i -2885.760986-444.581451i -3876.727051-2624.972900i -3215.713623-363.830933i -2871.160645-827.096252i -3357.463867-1921.066040i -2551.175537-430.774689i -1476.347778+1748.158936i -408.644470+2422.092773i -984.690796+3129.027100i 2004.571167+8537.231445i 2392.158691+5320.046875i 4108.902832+3927.633789i 3545.595459+2921.787842i 3005.838623+2436.031006i 4467.781738-693.343567i 4312.133301-2547.319824i 2124.886963-1133.958252i 1970.101562-1217.314087i 815.273682+600.949463i
```

Right Result

```
1922.457886+0.000028i 1590.333618+1077.984741i -742.876587+2197.919678i -3192.101562+1208.123901i -5565.625488+950.697571i -2885.760010-444.581543i -3876.726318-2624.972656i -3215.712646-363.830994i -2871.160400-827.095825i -3357.463623-1921.066406i -2551.175781-430.774475i -1476.347900+1748.158936i -408.644318+2422.092529i -984.690857+3129.026367i 2004.571289+8537.230469i 2392.158691+5320.046875i 4108.902344+3927.633789i 3545.594971+2921.787842i 3005.838623+2436.031006i 4467.781738-693.343872i 4312.133301-2547.319336i 2124.886963-1133.958130i 1970.101440-1217.313721i 815.273743+600.949463i
```

Complex Float Matrix A 24 x 24

```
846.034424+0.000000i 692.429993-79.920929i 299.893677-173.686523i 117.934189-249.438538i -397.368805-307.499542i -200.135315-122.347252i -317.231934-34.053032i -228.393478-392.325012i -127.726959-492.413513i -472.311096-325.571991i -510.262024-382.537262i -350.180908-294.300842i -293.310211-433.513275i -292.838348-622.537598i -248.129822-780.637817i 73.105545-369.854614i 311.308044-476.008270i 269.632812-434.859344i 297.421509-367.780273i 422.382996-267.411438i 847.454346+0.086609i 417.832062+135.523224i 634.468994+79.585495i 562.956360+28.823025i
692.429993+79.920929i 729.823608+0.000000i 433.412445-176.004471i 279.240112-333.730011i -247.280304-623.308289i -178.082199-249.672516i -405.823608-229.667175i -221.934280-552.801086i -159.924622-733.100281i -584.464539-557.959167i -513.812439-557.605591i -287.260925-363.278137i -172.812073-393.315796i -126.653442-645.273193i 234.461395-497.079224i 404.682709-167.057907i 440.305817-173.756729i 344.074280-209.670471i 343.704895-161.842102i 330.104797-66.911331i 650.627319+119.730247i 327.168274+228.784500i 448.958160+166.081177i 576.669861+93.079895i
299.893677+173.686523i 433.412445+176.004471i 663.860657+0.000000i 748.176208-369.171478i 416.053192-800.157959i 156.839417-424.814667i -66.856201-704.243286i 48.570087-671.490234i 19.534491-851.697327i -300.561401-772.196716i -252.325562-557.146790i -1.530064-85.880135i 53.092026-8.853506i 118.788445-253.089584i 613.292664+591.216370i 532.384949+546.371887i 237.907715+553.619873i 90.743271+368.473480i 141.670868+360.003815i -323.364014+181.914490i -148.321045+119.432144i -57.208363+161.784821i 30.676718+75.976265i 377.163757+126.714874i
117.934189+249.438538i 279.240112+333.730011i 748.176208+369.171478i 1352.880615+0.000000i 1126.432495-433.352936i 631.408752-354.911865i 683.227661-869.343262i 632.771423-605.632751i 558.547607-982.655090i 227.245529-983.722412i 97.741722-651.704468i 56.844387+134.000076i -10.137331+232.600876i 50.433235+4.382356i -150.310242+1466.185059i -49.551094+1006.306763i -492.348541+747.632629i -513.225464+481.005188i -351.553131+473.534912i -768.257263-210.671112i -438.366119-438.617279i -208.443069-26.301529i -77.328537-41.271057i 327.690460+278.439056i
-397.368805+307.499542i -247.280304+623.308289i 416.053192+800.157959i 1126.432495+433.352936i 1862.093872+0.000000i 893.866394-257.745972i 1074.619385-936.400269i 1080.759033-393.798340i 1080.445312-524.300049i 1011.214233-959.518372i 751.320740-563.206177i 421.583740+289.984283i 192.584259+499.200745i 437.832153+596.648315i -242.677963+2380.033691i -500.537079+1650.186523i -927.506714+1268.838135i -824.274353+888.214966i -694.109680+779.420105i -1105.235107-118.333450i -1049.157837-437.560486i -587.285156-124.098953i -431.681488-151.020599i -80.391388+461.592102i
-200.135315+122.347252i -178.082199+249.672516i 156.839417+424.814667i 631.408752+354.911865i 893.866394+257.745972i 543.277100+0.000000i 730.056763-328.768524i 586.875366-16.146624i 604.010132-139.252884i 594.211060-330.463440i 402.430389-166.598511i 155.124969+239.680237i 14.554134+282.846649i 67.461212+333.344971i -544.192322+1092.563965i -489.398132+682.415710i -660.956177+435.380310i -592.071167+283.615387i -481.770996+273.152588i -578.364807-284.839905i -432.705444-467.157928i -252.863144-177.831146i -184.364960-105.140976i -70.373978+192.619568i
-317.231934+34.053032i -405.823608+229.667175i -66.856201+704.243286i 683.227661+869.343262i 1074.619385+936.400269i 730.056763+328.768524i 1366.968384+0.000000i 925.953979+357.572357i 987.470398+227.252899i 1120.328857-116.214615i 720.144531+113.828911i 93.614426+436.813782i -174.339905+460.500732i -125.334450+536.489380i -1566.807861+1231.646362i -1241.660278+685.666565i -1289.289917+110.175888i -1030.719727+10.466843i -849.454102+15.663177i -637.056580-776.948059i -307.042267-905.982361i -203.836639-352.417480i -150.287170-344.785004i -200.414276+181.432739i
-228.393478+392.325012i -221.934280+552.801086i 48.570087+671.490234i 632.771423+605.632751i 1080.759033+393.798340i 586.875366+16.146624i 925.953979-357.572357i 1023.432495+0.000000i 1085.747070-106.506378i 951.967957-544.681274i 813.398071-377.059845i 315.068604+17.699055i 180.264069+150.657867i 375.880463+189.927933i -601.740784+1099.747559i -647.649109+755.437317i -722.275391+403.219574i -489.099426+294.049866i -442.473572+232.180328i -365.307831-185.589325i -361.585815-195.537323i -255.364120+12.100807i -154.270142+108.992714i -145.517654+461.467590i
-127.726959+492.413513i -159.924622+733.100281i 19.534491+851.697327i 558.547607+982.655090i 1080.445312+524.300049i 604.010132+139.252884i 987.470398-227.252899i 1085.747070+106.506378i 1459.037720+0.000000i 1145.059692-616.668396i 975.515930-451.436035i 297.028229-125.700050i 179.042145-5.695498i 471.569214+52.771812i -827.958557+694.131958i -721.609009+679.779724i -680.237000+173.968353i -418.373901+94.836716i -401.116058+90.706520i -130.420578-310.272217i 16.708679-108.416885i -171.285599+47.552147i -109.981544+160.078156i -182.209366+615.671204i
-472.311096+325.571991i -584.464539+557.959167i -300.561401+772.196716i 227.245529+983.722412i 1011.214233+959.518372i 594.211060+330.463440i 1120.328857+116.214615i 951.967957+544.681274i 1145.059692+616.668396i 1466.600464+0.000000i 1097.442139+148.505630i 390.618164+268.185699i 96.993210+299.075256i 384.726807+593.591919i -1139.338013+891.152893i -1071.154663+551.454407i -913.621521+200.369247i -644.001709+140.031479i -533.023804+126.435074i -359.098083-336.750305i -339.591888-220.743805i -412.548798-126.666504i -311.889130-30.953690i -458.171875+459.022369i
-510.262024+382.537262i -513.812439+557.605591i -252.325562+557.146790i 97.741722+651.704468i 751.320740+563.206177i 402.430389+166.598511i 720.144531-113.828911i 813.398071+377.059845i 975.515930+451.436035i 1097.442139-148.505630i 1074.651611+0.000000i 498.815552+56.508560i 367.963562+203.591965i 615.645020+403.514679i -350.488464+733.823608i -504.463165+504.889038i -504.662231+343.320801i -278.440002+305.153259i -279.109680+218.992584i -215.620941+113.587891i -397.410400+153.275726i -364.260803+47.977142i -448.225433+178.677902i -488.958679+429.138702i
-350.180908+294.300842i -287.260925+363.278137i -1.530064+85.880135i 56.844387-134.000076i 421.583740-289.984283i 155.124969-239.680237i 93.614426-436.813782i 315.068604-17.699055i 297.028229+125.700050i 390.618164-268.185699i 498.815552-56.508560i 665.190491+0.000000i 518.804199+168.709900i 671.654785+350.977234i 719.247009+684.347839i 248.052338+503.694885i 134.574005+564.267334i 110.810654+599.050964i 56.786274+445.408478i -318.087860+609.023926i -716.544556+473.061127i -408.837891+194.474060i -481.766632+230.151093i -246.862701+160.150284i
-293.310211+433.513275i -172.812073+393.315796i 53.092026+8.853506i -10.137331-232.600876i 192.584259-499.200745i 14.554134-282.846649i -174.339905-460.500732i 180.264069-150.657867i 179.042145+5.695498i 96.993210-299.075256i 367.963562-203.591965i 518.804199-168.709900i 596.381104+0.000000i 658.443665+61.984833i 1171.753784+223.644882i 596.661865+292.638000i 469.755066+528.914429i 391.641907+546.784607i 274.620239+424.423920i -46.843994+753.871216i -508.842896+737.788269i -259.924133+301.629944i -407.842957+388.554260i -225.513992+205.022705i
-292.838348+622.537598i -126.653442+645.273193i 118.788445+253.089584i 50.433235-4.382356i 437.832153-596.648315i 67.461212-333.344971i -125.334450-536.489380i 375.880463-189.927933i 471.569214-52.771812i 384.726807-593.591919i 615.645020-403.514679i 671.654785-350.977234i 658.443665-61.984833i 1144.365723+0.000000i 1305.773193+508.463623i 661.182495+573.718689i 539.070435+793.422180i 518.548767+731.494141i 382.498535+613.297546i -90.722176+915.582764i -610.333862+1047.285767i -446.181244+489.562866i -474.825439+601.671753i -203.751114+436.086365i
-248.129822+780.637817i 234.461395+497.079224i 613.292664-591.216370i -150.310242-1466.185059i -242.677963-2380.033691i -544.192322-1092.563965i -1566.807861-1231.646362i -601.740784-1099.747559i -827.958557-694.131958i -1139.338013-891.152893i -350.488464-733.823608i 719.247009-684.347839i 1171.753784-223.644882i 1305.773193-508.463623i 4318.809570+0.000000i 2644.343506+449.373383i 2209.172119+1476.509277i 1656.379028+1356.728760i 1335.566406+1139.391968i 125.797470+2222.154053i -981.744446+2262.200928i -372.699738+1000.520752i -583.253174+913.777161i 31.316895+133.036316i
```

```
73.105545+369.854614i 404.682709+167.057907i 532.384949-546.371887i -49.551094-1006.306763i -500.537079-1650.186523i -489.398132-682.415710i -1241.660278-685.666565i -647.649109-755.437317i -721.609009-679.779724i -1071.154663-551.454407i -504.463165-504.889038i 248.052338-503.694885i 596.661865-292.638000i 661.182495-573.718689i 2644.343506-449.373383i 1899.158691+0.000000i 1571.137817+669.227417i 1185.707031+622.001343i 980.242859+555.854675i 253.755554+1314.171753i -266.998779+1370.270508i -76.858734+616.759155i -252.419952+576.459473i 180.056366+24.800514i
311.308044+476.008270i 440.305817+173.756729i 237.907715-553.619873i -492.348541-747.632629i -927.506714-1268.838135i -660.956177-435.380310i -1289.289917-110.175888i -722.275391-403.219574i -680.237000-173.968353i -913.621521-200.369247i -504.662231-343.320801i 134.574005-564.267334i 469.755066-528.914429i 539.070435-793.422180i 2209.172119-1476.509277i 1571.137817-669.227417i 1794.500244+0.000000i 1392.082764+123.047852i 1197.870117+105.130913i 813.190857+1122.070068i 368.482544+1512.123291i 135.819824+712.409607i 104.829391+691.758789i 221.265656+100.566467i
269.632812+434.859344i 344.074280+209.670471i 90.743271-368.473480i -513.225464-481.005188i -824.274353-888.214966i -592.071167-283.615387i -1030.719727-10.466843i -489.099426-294.049866i -418.373901-94.836716i -644.001709-140.031479i -278.440002-305.153259i 110.810654-599.050964i 391.641907-546.784607i 518.548767-731.494141i 1656.379028-1356.728760i 1185.707031-622.001343i 1392.082764-123.047852i 1191.089600+0.000000i 981.677734+0.525019i 832.859985+892.794861i 422.683746+1340.630859i 158.256927+615.968750i 127.012207+631.991089i 124.453873+152.195755i
297.421509+367.780273i 343.704895+161.842102i 141.670868-360.003815i -351.553131-473.534912i -694.109680-779.420105i -481.770996-273.152588i -849.454102-15.663177i -442.473572-232.180328i -401.116058-90.706520i -533.023804-126.435074i -279.109680-218.992584i 56.786274-445.408478i 274.620239-424.423920i 382.498535-613.297546i 1335.566406-1139.391968i 980.242859-555.854675i 1197.870117-105.130913i 981.677734-0.525019i 874.943848+0.000000i 650.318237+737.438965i 395.459717+1105.509155i 118.616898+537.736084i 155.301575+517.932190i 157.675156+131.327255i
422.382996+267.411438i 330.104797+66.911331i -323.364014-181.914490i -768.257263+210.671112i -1105.235107+118.333450i -578.364807+284.839905i -637.056580+776.948059i -365.307831+185.589325i -130.420578+310.272217i -359.098083+336.750305i -215.620941-113.587891i -318.087860-609.023926i -46.843994-753.871216i -90.722176-915.582764i 125.797470-2222.154053i 253.755554-1314.171753i 813.190857-1122.070068i 832.859985-892.794861i 650.318237-737.438965i 1381.634399+0.000000i 1337.857056+715.259033i 568.533447+359.579956i 542.796326+454.030304i 110.482903+176.107452i
847.454346-0.086609i 650.627319-119.730247i -148.321045-119.432144i -438.366119+438.617279i -1049.157837+437.560486i -432.705444+467.157928i -307.042267+905.982361i -361.585815+195.537323i 16.708679+108.416885i -339.591888+220.743805i -397.410400-153.275726i -716.544556-473.061127i -508.842896-737.788269i -610.333862-1047.285767i -981.744446-2262.200928i -266.998779-1370.270508i 368.482544-1512.123291i 422.683746-1340.630859i 395.459717-1105.509155i 1337.857056-715.259033i 1952.827637+0.000000i 838.842346+146.530212i 886.247437+144.815430i 416.609985+122.532043i
417.832062-135.523224i 327.168274-228.784500i -57.208363-161.784821i -208.443069+26.301529i -587.285156+124.098953i -252.863144+177.831146i -203.836639+352.417480i -255.364120-12.100807i -171.285599-47.552147i -412.548798+126.666504i -364.260803-47.977142i -408.837891-194.474060i -259.924133-301.629944i -446.181244-489.562866i -372.699738-1000.520752i -76.858734-616.759155i 135.819824-712.409607i 158.256927-615.968750i 118.616898-537.736084i 568.533447-359.579956i 838.842346-146.530212i 489.622803+0.000000i 451.492249-41.529167i 245.236725-116.707436i
634.468994-79.585495i 448.958160-166.081177i 30.676718-75.976265i -77.328537+41.271057i -431.681488+151.020599i -184.364960+105.140976i -150.287170+344.785004i -154.270142-108.992714i -109.981544-160.078156i -311.889130+30.953690i -448.225433-178.677902i -481.766632-230.151093i -407.842957-388.554260i -474.825439-601.671753i -583.253174-913.777161i -252.419952-576.459473i 104.829391-691.758789i 127.012207-631.991089i 155.301575-517.932190i 542.796326-454.030304i 886.247437-144.815430i 451.492249+41.529167i 716.092957+0.000000i 398.925232-20.062534i
562.956360-28.823025i 576.669861-93.079895i 377.163757-126.714874i 327.690460-278.439056i -80.391388-461.592102i -70.373978-192.619568i -200.414276-181.432739i -145.517654-461.467590i -182.209366-615.671204i -458.171875-459.022369i -488.958679-429.138702i -246.862701-160.150284i -225.513992-205.022705i -203.751114-436.086365i 31.316895-133.036316i 180.056366-24.800514i 221.265656-100.566467i 124.453873-152.195755i 157.675156-131.327255i 110.482903-176.107452i 416.609985-122.532043i 245.236725+116.707436i 398.925232+20.062534i 547.669617+0.000000i
```

I tried using complex doubles and increasing iterations with no change to the returned values.  I've also tried normalizing the Eigen Vectors to further identify they do not match what Matlab produces.

Comment: Your matrix is [defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix) and only has 8 unique eigen vectors. The first 16 entries are simply numerical noise that is left over

Comment: More info... Matlab produces valid eigen vectors and values for all 16 entries.  These are validated using the right and left computation identified above.  Eigen library fails the first 16 with values and vectors that fail the right and left computation.  If a Matrix was defective how could Matlab still find a solution?  After the computation of invalid values and vectors Eigen Library still reports the operation was a success.

Comment: When I try your computation, I don't see significant deviations. `(left - right).norm()` is well below 0.01 for all vectors. You can also try using the [`SelfAdjointEigenSolver`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SelfAdjointEigenSolver.html) since your matrix has that pattern. Matlab tends to auto-detect those. Eigen expects you to know your matrices. But regardless, there is no meaningful information in an eigen-vector whose eigen-value is almost 300,000 times smaller than the smallest unique eigen-value. You're chasing numerical noise.

Comment: I just tried SelfAdjointEigenSolver.  It produces different numbers that are incorrect as well.  Good to try though.

Comment: The formula to prove correctness of eigen values and vectors is Matrix * vector == value * vector.  Validation cannot be (left-right).norm()<.01.  The values for the first 16 incorrect results are so small that the result of multiplying them by Matrix or vector (both are already normalized in this case) will just shrink their resultant values.  So the norm of the difference is going to be small simply because the values were small to start with.  Again, not proving correctness of the values or vectors but just their magnitudes.

Comment: I don't know how else to tell you, man: It's noise. There is nothing there. I've run the same matrix through Eigen, through Lapack, through MKL. They all produce the same with slightly different noise. The correct result with infinite precision would be zero because your matrix only has 8 unique eigen-vectors.If Matlab does something to those vectors to fulfill that property that you test, good for them. But it's still useless since there is no meaningful information in those vectors. You cannot magically invent new vectors for a defective matrix.

Comment: I think you are looking at it as physics and I'm looking at it as mathematics.  We have a Hermitian matrix and a function to calculate the eigen values and vectors such that the Matrix * eigen_vector == eigen_value * eigen_vector.  If the values cannot be put through the formula then they are not correct.  The correct Eigen value for the lowest value is  -2.926882300339260e-04. Did you get that result with lapack or MKL?

Comment: No, I get -0.00124324 using the selfadjoint solver but since I used the copied values from your question, there may be rounding errors in the input. You can check for yourself as Eigen can use [MKL as a backend for this calulation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html). Note that floating point numbers are not real numbers. It's a different arithmetic. It does have a rigid mathematical foundation, error bounds, etc. But you cannot expect the absolute precision that you get from an infinitely precise real number. See https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163

Comment: BTW: You don't need to go as far as an eigen solver to see this. Just compute `floor(0.49999999999999994 + 0.5)`, which is 1.0 under floating point arithmetic. That's obviously wrong. But that's how floating point numbers work. You've got to learn to deal with it

Comment: Oh, and [Matlab also states](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html#btwhou4-1) that it can only approximate the condition that you test: *Ideally, the eigenvalue decomposition satisfies the relationship. Since `eig` performs the decomposition using floating-point computations, then `A*V` can, at best, approach `V*D`. In other words, `A*V - V*D` is close to, but not exactly, 0.*

Comment: For eigan values greater than 1, the precision is 7 digits.  For eigen values less than 1, precision is much worse:  -.0002926 ML vs -0.000923 EL. Complex double didn't help much so I don't think we are losing precision from using a single.  I'm now hoping to find a library that gives better results for these small eigen values..

Comment: Could you try Matlab's `eig(A,"nobalance")` version to see if that replicates the result in Eigen? That would narrow down the difference in algorithm. Regarding precision, I think a fairer comparison involves the scale of the proper eigen values compared to the "practically zero" ones and that is at least a factor of 3e5, which is pretty good for single precision

Comment: Matlab hits 7 digits of precision sometimes 8 or 9 on all eigen values when comparing the left and right calculations. A difference of .0000001. for matlab while Eigen difference between right and left is .01 from what you reported earlier.  I have to conclude, if I'm using the library correctly, that the resolution is not good enough for my purposes.

Comment: eig(A,"nobalance") produces the same values as eig(A).

Answer (score 0):

The complex float matrix is N by N hermitian, and therefore must have N valid eigen values.  After going back and forth with a person responding to my Eigen Library bug submittal, there was no progress on resolving the issue.  What they do not tell you is that the Eigen solver has extremely limited precision.  So limited that it's useless for complex matrixes. It appears that the only way this minimally works is if all the returned values happen to be within 8 decimal places. They say 8, but it looks more like 6. There is definitely a huge lack of proper resolution in the internals of the method they came up with which unfortunately means that this is kind of useless as an Eigen solver for a complex matrix. This issue is compounded because when they exceed their internal extremely limited precision level, they still report success while returning incorrect values. The position from the person responding to the reported bug, is that it is not a bug because the results are exactly what they expect from their undocumented extremely limited precision. It appears there just another group trying to make people believe they have a valid solution when they do not. I did have some luck producing my own QR decomposition method to determine Eigen values but unfortunately that is an estimation algorithm and even though I got better precision than Eigen Library but it still wasn't good enough for me to accept it.  If anyone has a functional complex Eigen decomposition method out there that actually works, feel free to respond.